# What type of coolant should I use on a Dacia Logan Laureate diesel (2016)?

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

What type of coolant can I use on a 2016 Dacia Logan Laureate diesel? It is a little low so want to top up and see if it lessens again. Its not in the owners manual.

Comment: Also, I will check my owner handbook later, but I believe it is listed in there.

Answer (score 2):

You are wise to ask. Mixing incompatible antifreezes types can cause the formation of a sludge that can/will block passages in your radiator and/or heater core – and maybe other places as well.

As a rule of thumb you'd be wise not to mix antifreezes with different colors, but matching color is not a guarantee. If you can't find the answer in the manual, I'd **strongly** suggest contacting a dealer to get the appropriate specs and some recommended brands.

In the meantime for a small top up I'd suggest adding straight distilled water. The small amount of dilution won't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Renault (the maker of the engine in your Dacia) recommends that you use coolant to their specification. Given that its quite a new vehicle, go to the dealership and they will be able to sell you the correct anti-freeze when you give them your reg.

I did the same with our Logan, they advised me not to use any of the universal products which need to be diluted with water. I obliged because the cost difference is fairly negligible and I didn't want to flush the system on a fairly new vehicle (just top up).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Renault Type D coolant is the only one they advise.

Halfords do sell Halford own brand OAT ready mixed which they say is okay for Dacia Logan diesal 2016.

But I didn't want to risk invalidating my warranty as the halfords one is a different colour so would be noticeable.

Seems fairly hard to come by Renault Type D coolant, so is slightly annoying have to go to the dealership to get it.

Comment: I wouldnt use it, the Halfords stuff is red, I believe yours is green. Even if its totally compatible, it makes it difficult to do a visual inspection later on.